# Cosmos DB SDK v3 Paginated entity querying crashes in app service with "PartitionKey has fewer components than defined the collection resource"

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Ran into an issue while trying to retrieve entities from a cosmos db with the SDK v3. While running the code locally it works as expected; however it crashes in the app service. The database is not migrated so there is no PartitionKey installed.

Consider the following snippet:

```
var results = new List<AutomaticUpgradePlanificationDocument>();

var query = this.Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<AutomaticUpgradePlanificationDocument>(
       continuationToken: continuationToken,
       requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions() { MaxItemCount = top.GetValueOrDefault(-1), PartitionKey = PartitionKey.None })
   .Where(predicate);

if (orderByExpression != null)
{
    if (isDescending.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression);
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(orderByExpression);
    }
}

using (var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator())
{
    if (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync(); //*** <- This line is the one that produces a fatal exception (when running from an app service, not locally)***
        results.AddRange(response.Resource);

        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
    }
    else
    {
        continuationToken = null;
    }
}
```

Note: the code is supposed to extract some entitites in a paginated format. Project running the snippet above is developed using the .Net Framework 4.7.2
Found a similar issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2030 but the solutions proposed have no effect.

The exception is:
`

```
PartitionKey has fewer components than defined the collection resource.

   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.PartitionKeyInternal.GetEffectivePartitionKeyString(PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition, Boolean strict)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.ExecutionContext.CosmosQueryExecutionContextFactory.<TryCreateCoreContextAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.AsyncLazy`1.<GetValueAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.LazyQueryPipelineStage.<MoveNextAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.NameCacheStaleRetryQueryPipelineStage.<MoveNextAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CatchAllQueryPipelineStage.<MoveNextAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception wa...
.....
...
..
```

`

Comment: What is the Partition Key Definition of the container that you are connecting to? You can view this on the Azure Portal on Data Explorer.